# Get thumbnail pdf with php + Imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

```
<?php 
    $dir_pdf = "http://example.com/test/uploads/test_file.pdf";
    $dir_thumbnail = "http://example.com/test/uploads/test_file.jpg"
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->readImage($dir_pdf);
    header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
    echo $im;
?>
```

In folder "uploads" i have a **pdf file** 
My server installed Imagick & Ghostscript 
Why this code can't run :) 
Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $im = new Imagick("uploads/test_file.pdf[0]");
    $im->setImageFormat("jpg");
    $type=$im->getFormat();
    header("Content-type: $type");
    echo $im->getimageblob();
?>
```

this is my code :) 
I put test_file.pdf in folder uploads 
it work ^^!